# Citing an employment contract using APA style

Tags: contract-law, legal-citation

I am not sure if this is the right community for what I'm looking for, but here goes.

I would like to make an APA style citation of an employment contract using LaTeX document generator for personal use.

I have found some resources in the [Purdue website](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/apa_legal%20references%20.html) regarding how to make APA citations of international treaties or other major legal agreements. However I'm not sure if the same is applicable for a simply employment contract between employer and employee.

Has anyone ever had to make a proper citation of an employment contract using APA style? If so please let me know what is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: This is probably the wrong community.  Possibly [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit (e.g., [Citation-Style](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/citation-style/info) ).

Comment: A citation style for a personal letter would be more appropriate. Citations of treaties and legal agreements presume a common repository of authority that a third-party could check, while an individual contract or letter does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is no worldwide standard for legal citation

Each nation uses its own style and citation guide. Most of these will indicate how to reference contracts. However, in most cases they will simply be an ad hoc method of unambiguously identifying the contract “The contract between X and Y for Z entered into on 12 Sometime 1666” or of identifying the documents that evidence the contract.

However, none of them use APA. APA is the American Psychological Association style and is used in medical and allied health and is an Author, Year in-line style. Legal citation is universally footnote style. If you want to use APA, a contract would be cited like any other unpublished document.

Comment: Legal citation is universally footnote style?

Comment: @bdb484 certainly in English language journals.

Comment: Ah, in journals. Yes -- I was thinking of primary-source materials.

Comment: Actually, most legal citation in pleadings is done inline, rather than in footnotes, in U.S. litigation practice with footnotes largely reserved for law review articles and court opinions. But, certainly it is not done in APA style.